# How to add password protection to a PDF File

Tags: c#, itext

I use the following code :

```
string WorkingFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
string InputFile = Path.Combine(WorkingFolder, "PSNOs.pdf");
string OutputFile = Path.Combine(WorkingFolder, "PSNOs_enc.pdf");
using (Stream input = new FileStream(InputFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
{
    using (Stream output = new FileStream(OutputFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
    {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(input);
        PdfEncryptor.Encrypt(reader, output, true, null, "secret", PdfWriter.ALLOW_SCREENREADERS);
    }
}
```

But it is creating another file and adding password to the output file.
But I don't want to create two files like the above. I want to give the password for the input file `PSNOs.pdf` with out creating the other file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be done this way unfortunately.

I would suggest you:

1. Create the unsigned PDF in the system TEMP folder
2. Sign it, outputting to the location and file name you want
3. Clean up - delete the temp file.

Answer (score 1):

**According to [itextsharp](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/) documentation it can set password in newly created pdf. It can not give password to existing pdf file.**

So your wishing to make password protected without creating new file is not possible by using [itextsharp](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/).   to make password protected pdf you have to use output file(which is created password protected by PdfEncryptor.Encrypt() method) and delete the input pdf.

You can see this [link](http://www.coderanch.com/how-to/javadoc/itext-2.1.7/com/lowagie/text/pdf/PdfEncryptor.html) also

Answer (score 1):

Create Password protected PDF using the iTextSharp

```
   string sourcePdf = @"D:\unsecuredfolder\unsecuredPage.pdf";
        using (Stream input = new FileStream(sourcePdf , FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
               //Passowrd the pwd for PDF security                 

   string destPdf = @"D:\securedfolder\securedPage.pdf";

         /sourcePdf  unsecured PDF file
       //destPdf secured PDF file

        {
            using (Stream output = new FileStream(destPdf , FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
            {
                PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(input);

                string Password="abc@123";
                PdfEncryptor.Encrypt(reader, output, true, Password, Password, PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please elaborate on how this code answers the question.